Close gaps / move mesh islands in a grid after scaling elements (geonodes)
I want to create a simple wall (or cobbled path, or something with blocks) with different block sizes. One way I've been thinking of doing this is to start with a grid, split the edges and scale the elements (there are a few examples of this, which use triangulation and dual mesh too).  This creates the following (quite obviously!):

Is there a way after doing this that I can move each mesh island along any particular axis (in this case 'Y') so that the gaps are closed?  I have tried various ways using ray casting, or trying to capture position attribute of each island... but unfortunately my understanding of geonodes is nowhere near good enough to work out how to do it.
I understand that there might be different ways of getting the desired results (many many ways I am sure), but I would be particularly interested in understanding how to work with mesh islands and being able to manipulate them on an individual basis.

Same problem as solved by me in the (wrong) answer here: Geometry Nodes: Translate each instance by bounding box dimension

Is this what you want?

@DanyaK That is exactly what I want (I know there is a way to stack with Accumulate Fields - but did you do this with moving mesh islands about?). Thanks.

I actually just moved the faces and not the islands, which I assume is not what you want. Do you need a solution that works with complex 3D shapes and isn't limited to just squares?

@DanyaK I think that would probably work - I'm only using squares,

Just for clarification: would you like a solution WITHOUT Accumulate Field  node ?

@StefLAncien Not necessarily, no.  Anything that works is good for me (I'm about to try to solutions I've been given).  Thanks

The solution I'm going to show only works if your objects are assumed to be single face objects, otherwise it will give the wrong result. The solution looks like this:

The idea here is to use the Accumulate Field node:

First of all, you simply find the freed space for each square after resizing them.

Then you use the Accumulate Field node. It will sum up the spaces, since that's the offset each square needs to be moved.

The accumulation needs to happen for each column, so I use integer division to group the faces correctly:




Now just use that node. I negate the value at the end, since I need to move each square back by the amount of space produced.

Overall, I think the solution is similar to what was suggested in the comments above. This is just a simplified version, as it is used for a simplified case. If you are not satisfied with this, then be sure to also check out the proposed solution. It also explains why the Mix node is used after the Accumulate Field.
Or you can wait until someone else comes up with a more advanced solution.

Thanks - this worked well. Many thanks
